Checking for EMPTY Excel VBA Dictionary item for a Key
I'm encountering an occasional issue where an Excel dictionary is spontaneously replacing a Key item with "Empty".  This occurs sometimes when executing a statement which does not refer to the Dictionary variable at all.  I know that sounds odd, but sometimes exiting Excel and re-opening the spreadsheet fixes the glitch.  So, it must be some kind of memory issue (at least some of the time).
Anyway, that's not what I'm asking about.  What I've been trying to do is figure out how to check for an Empty value.  I need to be able to check for Empty, and I cannot find a way to do so.  Checking for Nothing or Empty (IF (dict(key) is Nothing) or IF(dict(key) is Empty) do not work).  Those statements crash the same as if I try to use the returned value as a Column number in a Range (vba))
I have seen posts where people claim it's a Watch window issue.  While this might be the case when referring to the Watch content only, it's a "real" problem as when the Code attempts to reference the key item, it crashes.  I don't know of a way to verify variable content while debugging other that the Watch window (Hovering is showing the same values as I see in Watch if I step through).
Is there a special way to check for Empty in this situation?


IsEmpty(dict(key)) works for me. How are you populating the dictionary?

If you check IsEmpty(dict("blah")) and "blah" isn't already a key, it will auto-create the key and IsEmpty() will return True    If "blah" is already a key then it depends on the associated value.  So before checking for Empty you should first ensure the key exists.

IsEmpty is something I do with cell ranges, not dictionaries.  IsEmpty (for ranges) doesn't work for me at all.  Checking ranges to see if any cells have non-blank or non-empty content in VBA always returns FALSE.
My original post was asking how do I check if a defined dictionary key has an EMPTY item - ile., dict("key") is empty, where dict.items(##) is "Empty" where dict.keys(##)="Key"

I'm sorry - I thought this was still in draft.  And, yes, spontaneously would be shocking.  But, I figured out what I think the problem was after I thought I'd left this as a draft.
I discovered I mistakenly used a variable local to another routine in the statement in this one; similar to cells(xyz, dict(KEYVAR)) = "Hello There".  KEYVAR was supposed to be a value the routine had just finished determining calculating.  As I used the wrong variable name, referencing a non-existing key added it with empty.
Oddly, KEYVAR was local to another routine - as VB doesn't require pre-defining a variable, no errors or warnings were generated.
I'd never expected a variable to be available outside it's local scope.  I don't use certain variable names as global/public variables, and verified this was the case.  Somehow, the value of a local variable in another subroutine was used in the statement.  Hovering showed consistent values.  That fooled me during debugging as the value it used was consistent with what was possible, just not what it should have been.  It wasn't until I added the variable to Watch and it showed "expression not defined" that I unraveled the cause.
I've got a habit of using common local variable names for similar tasks in multiple routines (wRow, wCol, wRange, etc), never thinking reusing a name would cause problems outside it's local scope.  I might have to revisit that practice.  In this case, the variable name in question is used in 12 other routines.  I know scope is a tried and true methodology, and one I've used and relied on for decades, so it has to be something I've done  I didn't pursue the why/wherefore this happened once I fixed the code, but it wasn't obvious.
Anyway, once I corrected the variable name used, the dictionary variable behaved as expected.

I highly doubt that the item of a dictionary changes "spontaniously". A Dictionary is an object that exists since a really long time and it is more than unlikely that such a bug in the Scripting library exists. Personally, I use Dictionaries all the time and never had such a case.
As you don't show your code, all we can do is guess. I assume that you
Either have a statement that tries to access a member of the dictionary that doesn't exist at that time:
If rawcolumns("Parcel") = 123 Then 

would add an entry with the key "Parcel" and an empty value when it doesn't exist.
Or you simply write the content of an empty cell or an unititialized Variant variable:
rawcolumns.Add "Parcel", ActiveCell.Value

would add an entry with the key "Parcel" and an empty value when the active cell is empty.
Anyhow, check for empty is easy, just use the IsEmpty-function.
The check for Nothing fails - Nothing is something different than Empty: Nothing signals that an Object-variable doesn't have a reference to an object. Empty is the initial value of a Variant-variable.
The check Is Empty fails because the operator Is is used to check if 2 references are the same - so valid only for object variables.
Sub test()
    Dim d As New Dictionary
    Dim v As Variant
    
    d.Add "one", 1      '  Adds key "one" with value 1
    d.Add "two", v      '  Adds key "two" with empty as value
    v = "Hello"
    d.Add "three", v    '  Adds key "three" with "Hello" as value
    ' The following will add key "four" with empty as value
    If d("four") = "xy" Then MsgBox "That came unexpected"
    ' The following will add key "five" with whatever is the content of the active cell
    d("five") = ActiveCell
    
    For Each v In d
        Debug.Print "Key:" & v, "  Value:" & d(v), "  IsEmpty: " & IsEmpty(d(v))
    Next
End Sub

Output:
Key:one         Value:1       IsEmpty: False
Key:two         Value:        IsEmpty: True
Key:three       Value:Hello   IsEmpty: False
Key:four        Value:        IsEmpty: True
Key:five        Value:        IsEmpty: True

